# ORA-39776: fatal Direct Path API error loading table

Tags: datatable, oracle11g, odp.net

I am trying to pass a .NET Database into Oracle using OracleBulkCopy via the Oracle ODP.NET (Release 5 (11.2.0.3.20)):

```
        // Copy table to Oracle
        OracleBulkCopy bulkCopy = new OracleBulkCopy(cmdOra.Connection);
        bulkCopy.DestinationTableName = "INBOUND_JOB_TMP";

        bulkCopy.BatchSize = 10000;
        bulkCopy.BulkCopyTimeout = 300;
        bulkCopy.WriteToServer(dtJobs);

        bulkCopy.Dispose();
        bulkCopy = null;
```

The jobs are retrieved from an SQL Server database:

```
        SqlDataReader reader;
        cmdSql.CommandTimeout = 120;
        cmdSql.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
        cmdSql.CommandText = "DOWNLOAD_JOBS";
        cmdSql.Parameters.Clear();
        reader = cmdSql.ExecuteReader();

        // Retrieve Job records
        dtJobs = new DataTable();
        if (reader.HasRows)
        {
            dtJobs.Load(reader);
        }
        else
            Trace.WriteLine("No rows returned.");
```

One of the fields passed is a signature field:

```
    SQL Server:

    CREATE TABLE [dbo].[JOBS_DOWNLOAD](
        [UniqueId] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
        [MobileJobNo] [varchar](20) NOT NULL,
        [MobileJobStatus] [varchar](1) NULL,
        [TenantSignatureImage] [varbinary](max) NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
    (
        [UniqueId] ASC
    )


    Oracle:

    CREATE TABLE "DBA"."INBOUND_JOB_TMP" 
       ("UNIQUE_ID" NUMBER(20,0), 
        "MOBILE_JOB_NO" VARCHAR2(20) NOT NULL ENABLE, 
        "TENANT_SIGNATURE" BLOB) ;
```

Now when I run this code to copy rows of data from Sql Server to Oracle it works fine.  The signature image is copied across.

However, if the signature image is larger than around 4K in size, I get the following error message:

```
    Oracle.DataAccess.Client.OracleException was unhandled by user code
      HResult=-2147467259
      Message=Error in row '1' column '1'
    ORA-39776: fatal Direct Path API error loading table DBA.INBOUND_JOB_TMP 
    ORA-00600: internal error code, arguments: [25029], [2147483647], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], []
      Source=Oracle Data Provider for .NET
      ErrorCode=-2147467259
      DataSource=""
      Number=-2754
      Procedure=""
      StackTrace:
           at Oracle.DataAccess.Client.OracleBulkCopy.PerformBulkCopy()
           at Oracle.DataAccess.Client.OracleBulkCopy.WriteDataSourceToServer()
           at Oracle.DataAccess.Client.OracleBulkCopy.WriteToServer(DataTable table, DataRowState rowState)
           at Oracle.DataAccess.Client.OracleBulkCopy.WriteToServer(DataTable table)
           at JobDataSync.SyncTables.Jobs.PostJobs() in C:\Development\JobSyncService\JobDataSync\SyncTables\Jobs.cs:line 114
           at JobDataSync.SyncTables.Jobs.Sync() in C:\Development\JobSyncService\JobDataSync\SyncTables\Jobs.cs:line 42
           at JobDataSync.TransactionalDataSync.SyncData() in C:\Development\JobSyncService\JobDataSync\TransactionalDataSync.cs:line 73
           at JobDataSyncConsole.DebugConsole.syncTimer_Elapsed(Object sender, ElapsedEventArgs e) in C:\Development\JobSyncService\JobDataSync\Console\DebugConsole.cs:line 74
           at System.Timers.Timer.MyTimerCallback(Object state)
      InnerException:
```

If I wrote back to an SQL Server table, this problem does not exist.

Any ideas what is wrong?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

This problem occurs when pushing data onto an Oracle table defined as a global temporary table as opposed to a standard database table.

Oracle support log raised.